# Dynamically add page to Polymer iron-pages

Tags: polymer-1.0

Is there any way to add a new page to iron-pages dynamically? I have this iron-pages:

```
<iron-pages selected="0">
  <div>Abc</div>
</iron-pages>
```

And then I add a couple more pages dynamically:

```
document.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHtml = "Def";
  var ironPage = document.querySelector("iron-pages");
  ironPage.appendChild(newDiv);
  console.log(ironPage.items.length) // log 1 instead of 2
  ironPage.select(1) // nothing shown.
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you might need to use the Polymer.Dom Api

```
Polymer.dom(ironPage).appendChild(newDiv);
```

Also I think you may have made another error:

instead of

```
newDiv.innerHtml = "def";
```

do

```
newDiv.textContent = "def";
```

Comment: Had the same problem. Wrapping my element with Polymer.dom() worked like a charm for me!